# Javascript - Can you reuse Date() objects?

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

Is it possible to create a new Date() object to get the current date, and then later, after a certain period of time, reuse the same Date() object to get the new current time?

It appears that you have to create a new Date object everytime you want the current date/time.

In my particular application I'm wanting to run an animation and for every single frame of the animation I need to aquire the current time. So creating a new Date object every single frame (potentially for 1000's of frames?) is just going to boost memory usage over time.

Any clues on this one?

Comment: If you're creating a new `Date` object but then dropping the reference to the old one then the garbage collector will get it and the memory usage won't grow over time.

Comment: Your intuition is right, and the answers below have some good options. It's worth noting, though, that it's more conventional to use [`setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/) for animation in JavaScript, and if you're targeting only modern browsers you should look into [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozRequestAnimationFrame#AutoCompatibilityTable). Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you're storing them separately, your date objects are garbage collected automatically. Moreover you can create store the current date to the same variable every iteration and not have to worry about memory blooming.

For example:

```
var current = new Date()
for (var idx = 0; idx <= frameCount; ++idx) {
    current = new Date();

      // Do processing...
}
```

You do not use more and more memory in this case because the old date will be garbage-collected after it has been overwritten.

Comment: I think the problem with `new Date()` in an animation frame is not so much the memory usage blooming, but the garbage collection pauses/jitters that will happen during your animation while it cleans up the discarded objects.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't actually want the date, but rather the time in milliseconds, use `Date.now()` so you don't have to create a `Date` object.

```
var t = Date.now(); // 1318479105311
```

You can shim it into older browsers with:

```
if( !Date.now ) Date.now = function(){ return +(new Date); };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a modern browser, call

```
Date.now()
```

which returns a number containing the epoch time.

Numbers are primitives in JavaScript so you are not creating any new objects.  But as others have said, the new objects are not too big of a deal.

Still you might be interested in this approach, especially if you do not need the year, month, and day, and will be satisfied with the epoch time.  I suppose if you really *wanted* to reuse a date object, you can call setters with values derived from the epoch time, but I don't think this approach buys you anything.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers have the `Date.now()` method which returns the <strike>epoch</strike> time without creating an object. IE has it since version 9.

I'm not sure this would give much of an advantage though, creating an object is pretty cheap. As @icktoofay pointed out, if you don't keep the old dates around they will be garbage collected.

edit: [here's a benchmark on both](http://jsperf.com/date-now2). `Date.now` is actually twice as fast in Chrome, but being in the > 3mhz zone I don't think this will matter for animations.